# I can't make the text appear on the page after an align, (overfull \hbox)

Tags: spacing

Can anyone help the text appear on the page and try and keep it in the align

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in}

\begin{document}
\section{Experience}
                            \begin{alignat*}{2}
                                             \text{Maintenence Worker} &- \text{Summers 2010 and 2011} &&- \text{Responsibilities included ensuring the upkeep of the grounds, being on-call to answer immediate problems, time management and working to a strict deadline} \\
                                    \text{Holt Hall Media Rep} &- \text{November 2011 to Present} &&- \text{Responsibilities included building a website for the Hall to advertise to new students, regular photography, regular videography, creativity and drive to improve the hall of residence} \\
                                    \text{Head of School} &- \text{Saint Felix School} &&- \text{Responsibilities included regular meetings with the headmaster to continue to provide ongoing support for students, driving the direction of the school from a pupil base, chairing a school council} \\
                                    \text{Head of Events, LCR} &- \text{2012 to 2013} &&- \text{Responsibilities included coming up with original and creative events for the radio station and continuing to promote and market the station} \\
                                    \text{Head of Quality Control, LCR} &- \text{2013 to Present} &&- \text{Responsibilities include working with presenters to push the station forward and working to build a unified station with high quality shows and a full schedule}
                            \end{alignat*}
```

Comment: You want a `tabular` rather than `alignat`

Comment: @egreg Would the rest of the code remain the same?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) With a `tabular` you can leave out all those `\text{...}` commands, since you are no longer in a math environment.

Comment: @mafp Thanks a lot, managed to get a working code :)

Comment: @mafp: Can you provide a small answer please?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Done.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, textual tabular material should go into a `tabular` environment. There, you specify column types, some of them take parameters. In the MWE below I used `p` columns that put their content in "paragraph boxes", i.e, treat table cells as justified text. The width of those columns is given in curly brackets after the `p` specifier. You may want to play around with those settings.

While typesetting quality tables is quiet an art (not only in LaTeX), the basics can be found in Section 2.11.6 of [lshort.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort-letter.pdf).

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\section{Experience}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5in}p{0.95in}p{2.25in}}
  Maintenence Worker
    & Summers 2010 and 2011
    & Responsibilities included ensuring the upkeep of the grounds, being on-call to answer immediate problems, time management and working to a strict deadline \\
  Holt Hall Media Rep
    & November 2011 to Present
    & Responsibilities included building a website for the Hall to advertise to new students, regular photography, regular videography, creativity and drive to improve the hall of residence \\
  Head of School
    & Saint Felix School
    & Responsibilities included regular meetings with the headmaster to continue to provide ongoing support for students, driving the direction of the school from a pupil base, chairing a school council \\
  Head of Events, LCR 
    & 2012 to 2013
    & Responsibilities included coming up with original and creative events for the radio station and continuing to promote and market the station \\
  Head of Quality Control, LCR 
    & 2013 to Present
    & Responsibilities include working with presenters to push the station forward and working to build a unified station with high quality shows and a full schedule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```